# Meaning of "run flat out"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

What does "I can run flat out for a half mile before my hands start shaking" mean?

It was said in [The Bourne Identity](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Bourne_Identity).

I am not a native English speaker. I know the meaning of the individual words, but have never heard the expression "run flat out" before.

Comment: [General Reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flat+out) *- flat out - **at top speed; "he ran flat out to catch the bus"***

Comment: **I have retracted my earlier closevote**. per comments under binarysubstrate's answer, although I still think the headline question  (what does it mean *here?*) is GR, the etymology of how the idiomatic *flat-out* came to have two now-distinct senses (*at top speed* and *bluntly, truthfully*) seems less clear-cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Flat out* is an expression used to describe one of three things, depending on the context:

1. Doing something as hard or as quickly as you can: e.g. *I worked flat out to finish the assignment.*
2. Doing something without hesitating or any second thought: *I flat-out disagree with your view.*
3. Lying down completely stretched out: *After winning the race, I was exhausted and collapsed flat-out on the ground.*

In this case, it's the second or the first use, depending on the context, though in either case he's making a statement about his physical condition. The speaker is saying one of two things:

1. He can run as quickly as he can for half a mile before his hands start shaking
2. The speaker can, without a moment's hesitation, run half a mile, without a warm-up, before his hands start shaking.

Comment: You're not 100% wrong, but it's misleading to suggest that #2 might apply *at all* in OP's context, let alone to mention is *first*. Besides which, your paraphrasing "He can run as quickly as he can" simply isn't a credible utterance.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that #1 makes more sense in the context of the movie.

Comment: Yes, #1 is the correct interpretation. The protagonist has an erased memory and is surprised to find out he has great physical training. Running flat-out for half a mile would send most people gasping for air :)

Answer (score 0):

## Meaning

Flat-out is an idiom which can be used in several contexts as already written by @newb. In the context of the original question it means to go at a maximum speed. Merriam-Webster offers several [definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flat-out) online (listed under "flat out" and "flat-out") including:

1. informal (chiefly US):  Absolute and complete.
2. Greatest possible. Maximum.

## Origins

@ws2 indicated flat-out may have originated with automobiles and specifically references having your foot flat on the accelerator pedal, similar to the phrase “Put the pedal to the metal.”

@oldcat indicated the origins may derive from horse racing where a rider or jockey must lie as flat as possible during a race to decrease wind resistance.

Intuitively both of these ideas seem plausible. However, if any origin is officially recognized, I haven’t found a reference to it yet.

(Rewritten based on comments.)

Comment: I'm afraid that's totally the wrong sense wrong for OP's context.

Comment: Don't be daft. Of course it has a definition. Probably several, but the dictionary I linked to under the question gives ***two***. The one which I copied into my comment is the one that applies here. Yours is the other, which doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to do with that link. Would it help you to know that OED definitely has the *relevant* definition, but appears not to explicitly include your *honestly, bluntly* sense at all. Which I'm sure is in any case a derivative of *at top speed -> quickly -> directly -> bluntly -> truthfully* (nothing to do with "lying flat, spread out, on the ground").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I haven't looked up the OED, but I always assumed 'flat-out' started in the age of the motor car. It is about having your foot flat on the accelerator pedal, isn't it? Australians, when overworked, will say 'I'm flat to the boards with so-and-so job'.

Comment: Running flat-out means running at top speed. Lying flat-out means not telling the truth without any hesitation or moral problems. Indeed two different meanings, but in the OP's example `flat-out` has nothing to do with honesty, but everything with physical prowess.

Comment: binarysubstrate: I can't win 'em all. It seems my *top speed ---> truthfully* is probably wrong (I need to look into how exactly the current divergent senses arose). @WS2: I'll (recklessly, given my last failure! :) guess that because ***all** out = flat out*, the *foot flat down on the pedal* idea is just a post-hoc "folk etymology". I now regret closevoting - the headline question (what does it mean *here*?) is trivial, and this answer is wrong, but the history of the two now-distinct senses looks potentially interesting, in that it doesn't seem obvious to *any* of us.

Comment: There could be another derivation of flat-out from horse racing. To achieve top speed the rider lies as flat on the horse as possible to decrease wind resistance.

Answer (score 0):

The only form that clearly makes sense is the Australian version that dates at least as far back as WWII: "Flat out like a lizard drinking." The implication of speed is from the lizard's tongue rapidly lapping up the water, which gets totally lost when shortened to just "flat out."

Comment: But that is not the original version. The expression "flat out" dates back to at least 1932, from England according to the OED. And it makes sense etymologically by itself because we also say "go all out".

Comment: (1) The question asks “What does ‘flat out’ mean?”  It means “at top speed”.  How is your answer to the question of *meaning* any different from the one that has been posted twice before?  (2) Are you claiming that this is the *source* of the idiom?  How does that make sense?  Why would anybody say “Flat out like a lizard drinking” unless “flat out” *already* meant “at top speed”?  (3) Are you saying that the “car” and “horse” explanations don’t “make sense”?  If so, why not?